# calculating rotate and translate position based on scroll value of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: This is the animation path that i want to acheive]

I want to move the object in my case its a plane along the shown curve on page scroll step by step taking into consideration the amount of scroll value.firstly the object moves in straight line and then after a point it changes its direction and move in that direction.How to calculate those co-ordinates?

Comment: Start by getting the formula for the trajectory. "y = -x^2" if you google search that it will start you on the right track. Or even "y = log(-x)". Then whenever you scroll you get the scrollTop of your containing element and enter it into the equation. If scrollTop == 100 then: 100 = -x^2.  For more complex paths you might want to specifiy the points in advance and interpolate between them. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: yup i understood the formula concept but a little more elaborate explanation would be helpful like calculating x's values or saving those in advance etc.

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could get this one. I'll try to explain both in detail.

Scenario 1: Simple path like in the question.

Scenario 2: Arbitrary complex path.

**Scenario 1:**
In this case you can use a simple formula. Let's go with `y = -x^2`. This will yield a parabola, which has a similar shape as the path in the question. Here are the steps for what to do next (we assume your scrolling element is the body tag and I assume you have jquery):

1. Get the "y" value of the body using the following code:

   `var y = $("body").scrollTop();`
2. Plug this value into the formula. I will give 3 examples where y is 0, 100 and 225 respectively.

   `//y=0
   0  = -x^2
   -x = sqrt(0)
   x  = +/- 0`

   So if we scroll and we are at the top of the page, then x will be zero.

   `//y=100
   100  = -x^2
   -x = sqrt(100)
   x  = +/- 10`

   The equation yieldsx as either positive of negative x but we only want positive so be sure to Math.abs() the result.

   `//y=225
   225= -x^2
   -x = sqrt(225)
    x  = +/- 15`

   From this you can see that the further we scroll down the more the object moves to the right.
3. Now set the "left" css of your object to the calculated value. This should be enough for this method.

**Scenario 2**
For more complex paths (or even random paths) you should rather put the x-values into an array ahead of time. Lets say you generate the array randomly and you end up with the following x-values:

```
var xvals = [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0];
```

We use normalized x-values so that we can later calculate the position independent from screen size. This particular series of values will cause the object to zig-zag across the screen from left to right, then back to left.

The next step is to determine where our scroll position is at relative to the total scroll possibility. Lets say our page is 1000px in height. `So if the scoll position is at zero then x = 0. If scroll = 500 then x  = screenWidth. If scroll = 250 then x = 0.5 * screenWidth` etc.

In the example I won't multiply with screen width for the sake of simplicity. But given the x value this should be simple.

The first thing you might want to get ready now is a lerping function. There is plenty of example code and so on so I trust that part to you. Basically it is a function that looks like this:

```
function lerp(from, to, prog);
```

Where from and to are any values imaginable and prog is a value between 0 and 1. If from is 100 and to is 200, a prog value of 0.5 will yield a return of 150.

So from here we proceed:

1. Get the scroll value as a normalized value

   `// scrollval = 200
   var totalScroll = 1000;
   var normScroll = scrollval/totalScroll; // answer is 0.2`
2. Before we get to lerp we first need to get the x-values to lerp from and to. To do this we have to do a sort of lerping to get the correct index for the xvals array:

   `// normScroll = 0.2
   var len = xvals.length; // 5
   var indexMax = Math.ceil((len-1) * normScroll); // index = 1
   var indexMin = Math.floor((len-1) * normScroll); // index = 0`

   Now we know the 2 x values to lerp between. They are `xvals[0]` which is 0, and `xvals[1]` which is 0.5;
3. But this is still not enough information. We also need the exact lerping "prog" value:

   `// We continue from the x indeces
   scrollRange.x = totalScroll / len * indexMin; // 0
   scrollRange.y = totalScroll / len * indexMax; // 250
   var lerpingvalue = (scrollVal - scrollRange.x) / (scrollRange.y - scrollRange.x);// 0.8`

   Now we finally have everything we need. Now we know we need a value between `xvals[0]` and `xvals[1]` and that this value lies at 80% between these two values.
4. So finally we lerp:

   `var finalX = lerp(xvals[0], xvals[1], lerpingvalue);// 0.4`
5. Now we know that the x coordinate is at 0.4 of the total screen size.
6. Trigger these calculations on each scroll event and you should be on your way.

I hope this was clear enough. If you try and try and can't get  results and can show how hard you tried then I'll be happy to write a complete index.html sample for you to work from. Good luck!

EDIT: I made a mistake with the lerpingval calculation. Fixed now.

Comment: I see I still have mistakes on that lerpval calculations. I'll try and fix them as soon as I have time to do so.